# Automatically add email addresses to outlook contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, contacts

Is there any way to automatically add the email address to my outlook contacts? Can we get option like adding email addresses from which I get mails or the addresses to which I send mails to the outlook contact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Outlook 2002-2007 does not include any built-in function to automatically add addresses to the Contacts.

You can use VBA code like that posted here: "[To automatically add recipients to Contacts in Outlook using VBA](http://www.outlookcode.com/d/code/autoaddrecip.htm)" to add the functionality.

> This VBA code sample by Sue Mosher provides a way to add recipients
>   automatically. To avoid the Outlook security prompts, it uses the
>   Redemption library, which provides a wrapper for Extended MAPI that
>   does not trigger the Outlook security prompts. You can download the
>   free version of Redemption for personal use. Use Tools | References in
>   VBA to add a reference to the SafeOutlookLibrary for your project.

Or perhaps checkout an add-on such as MAPILab's [Add Contacts](http://www.mapilab.com/outlook/add_contacts/).

> Add Contacts is an add-on for Microsoft® Outlook® that automatically
>   adds e-mail addresses to the contact folder when you reply to a
>   message and/or send a new message.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest another Outlook plugin: [OutlookMessagesEmailSaveFolder](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesEmailSaveFolder/#.VLc8LiuUds4).
Since it is free (for personal use), in contrast to MAPILab's.

On the other hand, MAPILab's plugin seems to be a bit more advanced:

- It adds contacts "when you reply".
- It "attempts to find Name"

Answer (score 0):

If this is important enough to you, consider upgrading to Outlook 2010, which provides a ['Suggested Contacts'](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2010/08/11/suggested-contacts-never-lose-an-email-address.aspx) feature.

As you send or receive email, the email addresses you would have otherwise lost will be automatically stored in a special contacts folder; from there, you just have to drag them into your normal contacts folder.  If you already have a contact with the same name, Outlook will offer to merge them.